# Regex in Custom Configuration Partially Working

Tags: c#, .net, regex, configuration

I have a `ConfigurationProperty` that is annotated with a `RegexStringValidator` that looks like this:

```
public class Test : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("field", IsKey = true)]
    [RegexStringValidator("issuer|subject")]
    public string Field
    {
        get { return (string)base["field"]; }
    }
}
```

It always throws an exception saying that the `RegexStringValidator` failed.  I can achieve success if I change the regex value to either of these:

- `"[a-zA-Z]*"`
- `".*"`

The actual "field" value being validated is the simple string "issuer".  I can see no reason why there should be a problem.  In fact, [the source code for `RegexStringValidator`](http://dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/fx/src/Configuration/System/Configuration/RegexStringValidator@cs/1/RegexStringValidator@cs) does nothing fancy; it simply uses a Regex and checks for success.

So I tried to do the regex directly as a test, the same way that it is done inside `RegexStringValidator`:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"issuer|subject", RegexOptions.Compiled);
bool match = reg.Match("issuer").Success;
```

The above works as expected; it returns Success==true.  I even used Telerik's "Just Decompile" to verify the System.Configuration source code indeed matches what is published online.

Again, I can see no reason why my "issuer|subject" `RegexStringValidator` regex constantly fails.

Any ideas?

The only clue I've turned up is when I tried the regex "[a-zA-Z]".  Strangely, this failed because it did not have the trailing asterisk.  So perhaps the regex must be written to match the full-length of the input.  To test that theory, I changed my regex to "^issuer$|^subject$", but that still didn't work when applied to the `RegexStringValidator`.  It does, however, work with my explicitly written regex test.

What makes the above anomaly interesting is that the source code for `RegexStringValidator` gives no reason of why "[a-zA-Z]" would fail.  Does this imply that the code I'm reflecting and seeing online does not match what is actually executing on my machine?  That doesn't seem plausible.  So this is weird indeed...

I'm using a .net 4.0 build, on a machine that has .net 4.5 installed.

Comment: How certain are you regarding the value of the field? (that it's "issuer", without any hidden/whitespace characters?)

Comment: Try `[RegexStringValidator(@"\s*(issuer|subject)\s*")]`. If there is any trailing/leading whitespace, this expression will match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

When the configuration system first creates the `ConfigurationElement`, it initializes each property to the empty string.  It then immediately runs the validation rules, including the regex.  The empty string does not match my regex, and so it fails before it ever had a chance to assign the real value to the property.

In short, there is a defect in the .net configuration infrastructure.

To compensate for this defect, I added a default value and an `IsRequired` requirement:

```
public class Test : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("field", IsKey = true, Default="issuer", IsRequired=true)]
    [RegexStringValidator("issuer|subject")]
    public string Field
    {
        get { return (string)base["field"]; }
    }
}
```

The default allows the `ConfigurationElement` to initialize without automatically failing the regex.   Unfortunately, this creates an unwanted side-effect because I don't want a default.  So I then need to compensate for the default by setting `IsRequired` to true.

This means the user is now forced to provide a value, and it will be correctly be validated by my regex.

Incidentally, now I understand why the regex statements `[a-zA-Z]*` and `.*` were "successfull."  It is because the asterisk means "zero to many".  When the property is initialized as the empty-string, and tested against either of these two regex statements, the "zero" requirement saves the day.  Of course that is not the behavior I want, but at least now there is no mystery.

Answer (score 0):

It's not strange that  "[a-zA-Z]" failed. It wouldn't match the entire string.

The rest of your problem does indeed seem odd. Maybe write your own code rather than depending on that of others when it behaves strangely?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the reg expression as

```
[RegexStringValidator("(issuer|subject)")]
```

Comment: Is the string only likely to be the 1 word?

Comment: the string is only ever "subject" or "issuer".